# i have problem when run c# and c++ program

Tags: java, c#, c++

i have source code like this one

```
namespace TrialCheck
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] urls = new string[] { "http://localhost:9900" };
            if (File.Exists("urls.txt"))
                urls = File.ReadAllLines("urls.txt");
                var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls(urls)
                .UseStartup<Program>()
                .Build();
            webHost.Run();
            
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Information);
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}

namespace TrialCheck
{
    public class Trial : Controller
    {
        [Route("ping")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Ping()
        {
            Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return Ok(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }

        [Route("loginid")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult LoginId()
        {
            try
            {
                string str = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(str);
                string res = TradingAPI.MT4Server.LoginId.Decode(bytes, 0).ToString();
                Console.Write(".");
                return Ok(res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                return new NoContentResult();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this code run well.
and here when the loginId.cpp

```
namespace TradingAPI
{
    namespace MT4Server
    {
        public ref class LoginId
        {
        public:
            static ULONGLONG Decode(array<Byte>^ data, int arg8)
            {
                pin_ptr<Byte> pData = &data[0];
                vLoginId login;
                return login.Decode((ULONGLONG*)pData, data->Length / 8, arg8);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and here for ulonglong we call vloginid.cpp

```
extern "C" ULONGLONG _aullrem(ULONGLONG a, ULONGLONG b);

int main(int, char**)
{
    return 0;
}

ULONGLONG t00D62EC8[64] = {
    0x145C311F09F7FC13, 0x35527CFB98BC2B31, 0x5648C8D827805A4F, 0x773F14B4B644896D,
    0x183560914508B88A, 0x392BAC6DD3CCE7A8, 0x5A21F84A629116C6, 0x7B184426F15545E4,
    0x1C0E900380197503, 0x3D04DBE00EDDA421, 0x5DFB27BC9DA1D33F, 0x7EF173992C66025D,
    0x1FE7BF75BB2A317A, 0x40DE0B5249EE6098, 0x61D4572ED8B28FB6, 0x02CAA30B6776BED5,
    0x23C0EEE7F63AEDF3, 0x44B73AC484FF1D11, 0x65AD86A113C34C2F, 0x06A3D27DA2877B4C,
    0x279A1E5A314BAA6A, 0x48906A36C00FD988, 0x6986B6134ED408A6, 0x0A7D01EFDD9837C5,
    0x2B734DCC6C5C66E3, 0x4C6999A8FB209601, 0x6D5FE58589E4C51F, 0x0E56316218A8F43C,
    0x2F4C7D3EA76D235A, 0x5042C91B36315278, 0x713914F7C4F58196, 0x122F60D453B9B0B5,
    0x3325ACB0E27DDFD3, 0x541BF88D71420EF1, 0x7512446A00063E0F, 0x160890468ECA6D2C,
    0x36FEDC231D8E9C4A, 0x57F527FFAC52CB68, 0x78EB73DC3B16FA86, 0x19E1BFB8C9DB29A5,
    0x3AD80B95589F58C3, 0x5BCE5771E76387E1, 0x7CC4A34E7627B6FF, 0x1DBAEF2B04EBE61C,
    0x3EB13B0793B0153A, 0x5FA786E422744458, 0x009DD2C0B1387377, 0x21941E9D3FFCA295,
    0x428A6A79CEC0D1B3, 0x6380B6565D8500D1, 0x04770232EC492FEE, 0x256D4E0F7B0D5F0C,
    0x466399EC09D18E2A, 0x6759E5C89895BD48, 0x085031A52759EC67, 0x29467D81B61E1B85,
    0x4A3CC95E44E24AA3, 0x6B33153AD3A679C1, 0x0C296117626AA8DE, 0x2D1FACF3F12ED7FC,
    0x4E15F8D07FF3071A, 0x6F0C44AD0EB73638, 0x100290899D7B6557, 0x30F8DC662C3F9475 };

ULONGLONG t00D630C8[64] = {
    0x145C311F09F7FC12, 0x35527CFB98BC2B33, 0x5648C8D827805A4B, 0x773F14B4B6448965,
    0x183560914508B89A, 0x392BAC6DD3CCE788, 0x5A21F84A62911686, 0x7B184426F1554564,
    0x1C0E900380197403, 0x3D04DBE00EDDA621, 0x5DFB27BC9DA1D73F, 0x7EF173992C660A5D,
    0x1FE7BF75BB2A217A, 0x40DE0B5249EE4098, 0x61D4572ED8B2CFB6, 0x02CAA30B67763ED5,
    0x23C0EEE7F63BEDF3, 0x44B73AC484FD1D11, 0x65AD86A113C74C2F, 0x06A3D27DA28F7B4C,
    0x279A1E5A315BAA6A, 0x48906A36C02FD988, 0x6986B6134E9408A6, 0x0A7D01EFDD1837C5,
    0x2B734DCC6D5C66E3, 0x4C6999A8F9209601, 0x6D5FE5858DE4C51F, 0x0E56316210A8F43C,
    0x2F4C7D3EB76D235A, 0x5042C91B16315278, 0x713914F784F58196, 0x122F60D4D3B9B0B5,
    0x3325ACB1E27DDFD3, 0x541BF88F71420EF1, 0x7512446E00063E0F, 0x1608904E8ECA6D2C,
    0x36FEDC331D8E9C4A, 0x57F527DFAC52CB68, 0x78EB739C3B16FA86, 0x19E1BF38C9DB29A5,
    0x3AD80A95589F58C3, 0x5BCE5571E76387E1, 0x7CC4A74E7627B6FF, 0x1DBAE72B04EBE61C,
    0x3EB12B0793B0153A, 0x5FA7A6E422744458, 0x009D92C0B1387377, 0x21949E9D3FFCA295,
    0x428B6A79CEC0D1B3, 0x6382B6565D8500D1, 0x04730232EC492FEE, 0x25654E0F7B0D5F0C,
    0x467399EC09D18E2A, 0x6779E5C89895BD48, 0x081031A52759EC67, 0x29C67D81B61E1B85,
    0x4B3CC95E44E24AA3, 0x6933153AD3A679C1, 0x08296117626AA8DE, 0x251FACF3F12ED7FC,
    0x5E15F8D07FF3071A, 0x4F0C44AD0EB73638, 0x500290899D7B6557, 0xB0F8DC662C3F9475 };

ULONGLONG d00D632C8 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D632D0 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D632D8 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D632E0 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D632E8 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D632F0 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D632F8 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63300 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63308 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63310 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63318 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63320 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63328 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63330 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63338 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63340 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
ULONGLONG d00D63348 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//+401000 c
vLoginId::vLoginId()
{
    s0 = 0;
    s8 = 0;
    s10 = 0;
    s18 = 0;
}

//+401040 c
ULONGLONG vLoginId::Decode(ULONGLONG* pData, size_t szData, int arg8)
{
    __asm
    {
        sub esp, 0x000001C0
        mov ebx, ecx
        mov ecx, dword ptr ss:[ebp + 8] //ecx = pData
        test ecx, ecx
        je l0130767D
        mov dword ptr ss:[esp + 0x00000034], 0
        mov dword ptr ss:[esp + 0x00000030], 0
        mov eax, dword ptr [ecx]
        mov ecx, dword ptr [ecx + 4]
        mov dword ptr ss:[esp + 0x0000002C], ecx
        mov dword ptr ss:[esp + 0x00000028], eax
        mov eax, dword ptr ss:[esp + 0x00000028]
        mov ecx, dword ptr ss:[esp + 0x0000002C]
```

i have build the class program as program.exe and it can be running well.
but when i hit using my java code

```
if (hdr.PackType == 9)
            {
                 LoginIdWebServer lid = new LoginIdWebServer();
                 //LoginIdWebServer2 lid2 = new LoginIdWebServer2();
                _LoginId = 0;
                 for (int i = 0; i < QC.LoginIdWebServerUrls.size(); i++) {
                    try
                    {// ini gue ubah
                        //_LoginId ^= ((long)_Account << 32) + _Session;
                        //throw new RuntimeException("Cannot recieve LoginID + Unreachable Ip" + QC.LoginIdWebServerUrls.get(i)+pack +QC.LoginIdWebServerTimeout+QC.Log);
                    _LoginId = lid.Decode(QC.LoginIdWebServerUrls.get(i), pack, QC.LoginIdWebServerTimeout, QC.Log);
                    if(_LoginId != 0) {
////                            //throw new RuntimeException("Cannot recieve LoginID + Unreachable Ip" + _LoginId );
                        QC.LoginIdWebServerUrlInd = i;
                            break;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.toString();
                    }
                }
                if(_LoginId == 0)
                    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot recieve LoginID + Unreachable Ip" + pack+"pack");
                //_LoginId ^= ((long)_Account << 32) + _Session;
                //_LoginId ^= 0x05286AED3286692AL;
                //LoginIdPow = lid.PowId;
//  _LoginId ^= ((long)_Account << 32) + _Session;
////                _LoginId ^= 0x05286AED3286692AL;

            }
        }
```

i cannot get the response from my loginwebserver here when i want to get the response

```
_LoginId = lid.Decode(QC.LoginIdWebServerUrls.get(i), pack, QC.LoginIdWebServerTimeout, QC.Log);

Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: Invoke failed: [[o:QuoteClient]]->Connect. Cause: online.mtapi.mt4.Exception.ConnectException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot recieve LoginID + Unreachable Ip[B@4390a022pack VM: 1.8.0_261@http://java.oracle.com/" at: #-14 online.mtapi.mt4.QuoteConnector.connect(QuoteConnector.java:96) #-13 online.mtapi.mt4.QuoteClient.Connect(QuoteClient.java:665) #-12 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

i cannot get the response well. so my code call this loginId=0 why like that ?

i also have built my loginId.cpp as loginId.dll.

here when i run my loginWebserver.exe from program.cs it is run well

[image]

Comment: ahh, that dumped ASM code. reminds of the days of creating key-gens. Start with `TradingAPI.MT4Server.LoginId.Decode`. What is the calling convention defined as in your C# program. Do you define it the same in the Java program? I'm just wondering if when Java invokes it, it's invoking with a `__cdecl` convention, or a `__stdcall` convention. If it's working well from a C# program, but not a Java program, either your params are wrong, or your calling convention is wrong. And shouldn't `ULONGLONG vLoginId::Decode` be `naked`? You are managing the stack in your ASM block.

Comment: Could you tag each code block with the language and tell us how they fit together?